# PHP - Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=20) state=0

Tags: plugins, ziparchive

I have come across this error for the first time and can't seem to debug it.

My code which concerns this error is as follows:

```
function save_contract( $post_id, $post, $update, $post_before ) {

        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        $date_of_contract = get_field( 'date_of_contract', $post->ID );

//Class Theme Helper
$template_file_name = require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/template.docx' );
$folder = require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/results_' );

 
$rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
$fileName = "results_" . $rand_no . ".docx";
 

$full_path = $folder . '/' . $fileName;
 
try
{
    if (!file_exists($folder))
    {
        mkdir($folder);
    }       
         
    //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
    copy($template_file_name, $full_path);
 
    // add calss Zip Archive
    $zip_val = new ZipArchive;
 
    //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
    if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
    {
        // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
        // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.
         
        $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
        $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);                
                     
        $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
         
        // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
        $message = str_replace("date_of_contract",      $date_of_contract,       $message);


        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
        $zip_val->close();
    }
}
catch (Exception $exc) 
{
    $error_message =  "Error creating the Word Document";
    var_dump($exc);
}


            
}

add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'save_contract', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Which part is throwing the error?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i dont know, in bug show me error  like  Parse error: in /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/seofy/template.docx on line 659
its sshow mee error in docx file!!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're doing this:

```php
$template_file_name = require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/template.docx' );
```

...but that's not how `require_once` (or `require`) works. [`require_once`](https://php.net/require_once) will load the file (or throw a warning if the file can't be included, eg, bad permissions or the file doesn't exist), but it will *not* return the filename; it will, instead, load the file and execute any PHP it finds therein.

A `.docx` file will *not* contain executable PHP code (if it does, you've got other problems).

In your case, the `.docx` file contains an [ASCII `20` character](https://www.ascii-code.com/20), which is `DC4`, Device Control 4. This is not expected in a PHP context, so PHP is throwing an error or a warning.

Instead of `require_once`, you might be looking for [`fopen()`](https://php.net/fopen) or some of [PHP's other filesystem functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).